# Getting Element of a attribute tag that is linked to a function after the search is compiled in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I have a JavaScript file that is using a for statement to generate the links in JavaScript and a Eventlistner to listen for a click event. I need it when I click on my a specific link from my generated a link thats connected to a function in HTML, I need the link to get and pass values from the link to the string but i am unable to set the values of the innerhtml of the a tag to a variable.

```
    <script>
    or (var j = 0; j < results.length; j++) {

            if (parseInt(results[j].distance.text) <800){


            geocoder.geocode({'address': destinationList[j]},
                showGeocodedAddressOnMap(true));

            outputDiv.innerHTML += '<a id ="cl" href="#">' +          results[j].distance.text + ' to ' + destinationList[j] +
                '. Destination is  ' + results[j].duration.text +' From '+ originList[i] + '</a><br>';

            }
          }


    var onChangeHandler = function() {
      display();
    }


    //EVENT LISTENER FOR LINK CLICK
    document.getElementById('output').addEventListener('click',       onChangeHandler);


    function Display(){

    var doc;
    doc = document.getElementbyId('cl').innerHTML;
    console.log(doc);



    }

    </script>
```

Comment: JavaScript and the DOM are case sensitive. So `document.getElementbyid` won't work. It needs to be `document.getElementById`. And be aware that it's "getElementById", not "ElementById" ...

Answer (score 0):

You can set the `onClick` attribute of `a` when you create it.

```
for(var j = 0; j < results.length; j++)
{
    if(parseInt(results[j].distance.text) < 800)
    {
        geocoder.geocode({ 'address' : destinationList[j] }, showGeocodedAddressOnMap(true));
        outputDiv.innerHTML += '<a id ="cl" href="#" onclick="onChangeHandler(' + j + '); return false">' + results[j].distance.text + ' to ' + destinationList[j] + '. Destination is  ' + results[j].duration.text +' From '+ originList[i] + '</a>.<br>';
    }
}

function onChangeHandler (i)
{
    alert(i);
}
```

You could pass additional parameters too:

```
for(var j = 0; j < results.length; j++)
{
    if(parseInt(results[j].distance.text) < 800)
    {
        geocoder.geocode({ 'address' : destinationList[j] }, showGeocodedAddressOnMap(true));
        outputDiv.innerHTML += '<a id ="cl" href="#" onclick="onChangeHandler(' + j + ', ' + results[j] + '); return false">' + results[j].distance.text + ' to ' + destinationList[j] + '. Destination is  ' + results[j].duration.text +' From '+ originList[i] + '</a>.<br>';
    }
}

var onChangeHandler = function(i, data)
{
    alert(data.distance.text);
}
```

Comment: if a i have a variable in javascript that i  need to pass into the onclick function, how do i pass it into the function without showing it in html?

Comment: For that you would need to use an anonymous function. `document.getElementById("...").addEventListener("click", function(){ functionYouWantToCall(varialbeYouWantToPass); });`.